# How to find closest form element in table row when using jquery datetimepicker input event close

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using xdan/datetimepicker jquery library to get date input. Upon date change, i need to change some form element in same row in table. here's the code

```
$('.tstartdate').datetimepicker({
    format:'d/m/Y h:i A',
      formatTime:'h:i A', step:1,
      onClose: function (ct, $i) {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td .enddate').val("zazazas");
            }
      });
```

```html
@:<td valign="top"><input type='text' class="tstartdate" value='@etadatetime' style='width:150px!important;'  name='Startdate' @flfirst /></td>
@:<td valign="top">
@:  <select name="Duration" class="selectduration">
@:  <option value="">Duration</option>
@:  <option value="12">12 Hours</option>
@:  <option value="24">24 Hours</option>
@:  <option value="48">48 Hours</option>
@:  <option value="72">72 Hours</option>
@:  </select>
@:</td>
@:<td valign="top"><input type='text' class='enddate' style='width:150px!important;'  name='Enddate' placeholder='To Date'/></td>
```

Comment: Can you post your table's HTML structure as well?

Comment: i just  added html (asp.net razor).   need to attach html form element with jquery plugin in multiple table rows data key in using class name , we can iterate the dom using jquery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) suggests that the input is passed as a second parameter (`$i` in your code) and that it's already a jQuery instance, so:

```
$('.tstartdate').datetimepicker({
    format:'d/m/Y h:i A',
      formatTime:'h:i A', step:1,
      onClose: function (ct, $i) {
          $i.closest('tr').find('td .enddate').val("zazazas");
// -------^^
      }
});
```

Assuming of course that the element you want to update is inside a `td` and has the class `enddate`.

Calling event handlers with `this` referring to the DOM element the handler was hooked to is the overwhelmingly-common convention in jQuery and well-behaved jQuery plugins, but it's not universal. This one appears to prefer a different API.